# what are the different ways you can optimize following function?

Tags: coding-style

what are the different ways you cawhat are the different ways you can optimize following function?n optimize following function?

if(a==1 || a==5 || a==-1 || a==7 ||a==-8 ||a==11 ||a==6 ||a=11 )
and again i want to add some more if condition in this function?

What are the different approach you can suggest?

Comment: **DO NOT USE! This tag refers to an entirely opinionated subject and is therefore no longer on-topic.** Questions that follow coding style and conventions.

Comment: ok..thanks for letting know.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this-------

1st- Create an int array(number array)
2nd- Add all the numbers you want to check
3rd- Finally check whether number 'a' is in the array. **ex- array[].includes(a);**